# created proxy with svcutil in .net core 2.2 send the request but can not get the result

Tags: wcf, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, svcutil.exe

I add a reference to a service in my .net core 2.2 project using svcutil 2.0.2 from here :
http://sms.magfa.com/services/urn:SOAPSmsQueue?wsdl

the created service proxy send the request to server and server send reply back to the us but the proxy can not get the result !!
we use this service in our asp .net web app but in .net core 2.2 using svcutil 2.0.2 we can not get the result.
what is the problem ?
thank you

my code :

```
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = null;
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = null;
        ChannelFactory<ServiceReference1.SoapSmsQueuableImplChannel> factory = null;
        ServiceReference1.SoapSmsQueuableImplChannel serviceProxy = null;

        try
        {
            basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
            endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://sms.magfa.com/services/urn:SOAPSmsQueue?wsdl"));
            factory = new ChannelFactory<ServiceReference1.SoapSmsQueuableImplChannel>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress);

            factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "**";
            factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "****";
            serviceProxy = factory.CreateChannel();

            //((ICommunicationObject)serviceProxy).Open();
            //var opContext = new OperationContext((IClientChannel)serviceProxy);
            //var prevOpContext = OperationContext.Current; // Optional if there's no way this might already be set
            //OperationContext.Current = opContext;

            using (var scope = new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)serviceProxy))
            {
                var result = await serviceProxy.getCreditAsync("***").ConfigureAwait(false);

            }

            factory.Close();
            ((ICommunicationObject)serviceProxy).Close();
        }
        catch (MessageSecurityException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            // *** ENSURE CLEANUP (this code is at the WCF GitHub page *** \\
            CloseCommunicationObjects((ICommunicationObject)serviceProxy, factory);
        }
```

Comment: Did some certain errors occur during adding service reference?
Moreover, I would like to know more about the error details during the invocation. In general, as long as we can generate a client proxy class correctly, the service can return results properly.

Comment: Hi. no error occur in adding service. service is added and we can call the methods. the request is processed in server but the client receive null as result !!